# Getting the value from a steam profile using importxml

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, steam

I wanted to create a google sheet where I put some steam profile links that I know are banned.
And in the row next to it I wanted to output via importxml how long they are already banned.

Steam Class for ban is:

```
<div class="profile_ban_status">
    <div class="profile_ban">
                    1 VAC ban on record                 
<span class="profile_ban_info">| <a class="whiteLink" href="https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7849-Radz-6869&amp;l=english" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">Info</a></span>
                </div>
                                    2306 day(s) since last ban                              </div>
```

My importxml looks like this:

```
=IMPORTXML(B3, "//div[@class='profile_ban_status']")
```

But it doesn't work.
Can anybody help me fix it?

Comment: Can you provide the URL of `=IMPORTXML(B3, "//div[@class='profile_ban_status']")`? And also, can you provide the output values you expect?

Comment: The URL is: `https://steamcommunity.com/id/071200` and the expected output would be `1 VAC ban on record`

Comment: When I try this, I get `1 VAC ban on record | Info` in one cell and ` 2306 day(s) since last ban` in another cell, which is to be expected considering the HTML. Do you want something else instead? When you say `But it doesn't work`, what do you mean exactly? You are not getting the results I mentioned?

Comment: Yes exactly.. With the IMPORTXML I provided in the post I get an error saying `Error on parsing formular` but I don't know how to fix it. The two outputs you mentioned with `1 VAC ban on record | Info` and `2306 day(s) since last ban` is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this since I'm getting the results you are looking for. Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on (free of sensitive information), in order to clarify this?

Comment: [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19X9ifhdP86zFeHM0AqYJ0r1dI_zLMTdjq5OzvTNKv_A/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: When I tested your formula of `=IMPORTXML(B3,"//div[@class='profile_ban_status']")`, no error occurs and the value of ` 1 VAC ban on record | Info` is obtained. So for example, how about `=IMPORTXML(B3;"//div[@class='profile_ban_status']")`? In this case, `,` is replaced with `;`. But I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue. I apologize for this.

Comment: Thank you so much! @Tanaike when I replaced the `,` with `;` it works now!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I thought that your question and the solution will be also useful for other users. So I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tested your formula of `=IMPORTXML(B3,"//div[@class='profile_ban_status']")`, no error occurs and the value of `1 VAC ban on record | Info` is obtained.

In this case, I would like to prpopose the following modification.

#### From:

```
=IMPORTXML(B3,"//div[@class='profile_ban_status']")
```

#### To:

```
=IMPORTXML(B3;"//div[@class='profile_ban_status']")
```

- In this modification, `,` is replaced with `;`.